# spark how to perform multiplication accumulatively along one column

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Here is a dataFrame in spark

```
+------+----+---+
| Close|sell|buy|
+------+----+---+
| 314.6|   0|  1|
|   120|   1|  0|
|   192|   0|  1|
|199.46|   1|  0|
|255.05|   0|  1|
|250.52|   1|  0|
|252.53|   0|  1|
|245.32|   1|  0|
-----------------
```

what I want to do is: for all rows of the first column, multiply them accumulatively, i.e. `314.6 * 120 * 192 * 199.65 ...` and I want to get the final value.

Comment: hi, could you indicate if the answer was of merit pls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deleted post was nearly there, but you are dealing with RDD of Row Type in order for the reduce to be applied, and have data like 120 and 134.4 which then has an issue with AnyVal with Row Type.

I suggest the following which takes into account the 123 and 123.5 formats:

```
case class Employee(first_name:String, job_type:String, salary:Double)

val dfE = spark.createDataFrame(
                                Seq(Employee("John", "sh_clerk", 20000), 
                                    Employee("Peter", "sh_clerk", 60000.0), Employee("Sally", "manager", 50000.0),
                                    Employee("Cabe", "programmer", 100000.0), Employee("Bob", "accountant", 65000.0)     
                               )
                           )


dfE.show(false)
dfE.printSchema()
dfE.select("salary").rdd.map(row => row.getDouble(0)).reduce(_*_)
```

which in this case returns the following with no exceptions:

```
res19: Double = 3.9E23
```

The case class is more for formality - as the RDD gets the AnyVal issue.

Comment: do you know how can i do this in java? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58632733/java-spark-multiply-all-rows-for-column